# MongoDb Database Modelling

Tags: mongodb

I have problem about , 1 object's data size. And I don't know is my data model true ? 
Here is situation:
I have 25 server , 200 server counter , and minute of day 1440 data.
My purpose saving   daily data of counter of server .
But query performance is important for me.

### I have 3 model in my mind , but I don't know which one is more compatible for my project.

### 1- Server Root:

My Data Model :

```
{ "_id":Object(....), 
    "serverId":0
    "counters": [ 
                     { "counterId":0 , "inserted": ISODate(...) , "counterValue":122.2131 , "min":121 , "max":33333} ,
                                                .
                                                .1440 times "counterId":0
                                                .
                     { "counterId":1 , "inserted": ISODate(...) , "counterValue":122.2131 , "min":121 , "max":33333} ,        
                                               .
                                                .1440 times "counterId":1
                                                .
                    .
                    .  200 Counters
                    .
                     { "counterId":200 , "inserted": ISODate(...) , "counterValue":122.2131 , "min":121 , "max":33333}         
                                               .
                                                .1440 times "counterId":200
                                                .
                       ] },
        .
        .
        .25 Server
        .
        .
{ "_id":Object(....), 
    "serverId":25
    "counters": [ 
                     { "counterId":0 , "inserted": ISODate(...) , "counterValue":122.2131 , "min":121 , "max":33333} ,
                                                .
                                                .1440 times "counterId":0
                                                .
                     { "counterId":1 , "inserted": ISODate(...) , "counterValue":122.2131 , "min":121 , "max":33333} ,        
                                               .
                                                .1440 times "counterId":1
                                                .
                    .
                    .  200 Counters
                    .
                     { "counterId":200 , "inserted": ISODate(...) , "counterValue":122.2131 , "min":121 , "max":33333}         
                                               .
                                                .1440 times "counterId":200
                                                .
                       ] },
```

Problems:
----Quering Performance Of Aggrigation Framework-- : 
When I try to find avarage counterValue of Counters for 1 day it takes : 12 seconds
---Data Size----
It is not possible to modelling like that 16 Mb fulled when I try.

---

### 2- Counter Root:

My Data Model :

```
 { "_id":Object(....),
        "counterId":0  
        "servers": [ 
                         {  "serverId":0, "inserted": ISODate(...) , "counterValue":122.2131 , "min":121 , "max":33333} ,
                                                    .
                                                    .1440 times "serverId":0
                                                    .
                         { "serverId":1 , "inserted": ISODate(...) , "counterValue":122.2131 , "min":121 , "max":33333} ,        
                                                   .
                                                    .1440 times "serverId":1
                                                    .
                        .
                        .  25 Server
                        .
                         { "serverId":25 , "inserted": ISODate(...) , "counterValue":122.2131 , "min":121 , "max":33333}         
                                                   .
                                                    .1440 times "serverId":200
                                                    .
                           ] },
            .
            .
            .200 Counter
            .
            .
    { "_id":Object(....),
        "counterId":200  
        "servers": [ 
                         {  "serverId":0, "inserted": ISODate(...) , "counterValue":122.2131 , "min":121 , "max":33333} ,
                                                    .
                                                    .1440 times "serverId":0
                                                    .
                         { "serverId":1 , "inserted": ISODate(...) , "counterValue":122.2131 , "min":121 , "max":33333} ,        
                                                   .
                                                    .1440 times "serverId":1
                                                    .
                        .
                        .  25 Server
                        .
                         { "serverId":25 , "inserted": ISODate(...) , "counterValue":122.2131 , "min":121 , "max":33333}         
                                                   .
                                                    .1440 times "serverId":200
                                                    .
                           ] },
```

Problems:
----Quering Performance Of Aggrigation Framework-- : 
When I try to find avarage counterValue of Counters for 1 day it takes : 7 seconds
---Data Size----
It is not possible to modelling like that 16 Mb fulled when I try., but I divided 2 pieces it's works.

---

### 3- Without Root:

My Data Model :

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("515921e3bbea58d25eb07b22"), "serverId" : 0, "counterId" : 0, "inserted" : ISODate("2013-03-21T00:26:30Z"), "counterValue" : 0.03256159112788737, "min" : -29.967438408872113, "max" : 20.032561591127887 }
.
.7 billion data
.
```

Problems:
----Quering Performance Of Aggrigation Framework-- : 
When I try to find avarage counterValue of Counters for 1 day it takes : 7 seconds

SO:
I could not decide which data model I must use ,

Thanks..

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you are choosing monogodb here.
I would use your third option but there is lack of indexes. add indexes for serverid and counterid fields and you'll get much better time.

Also you probably end up having separate collections for read and write , ie

-Use one collection as you do in your third option
-Once and hour/day/week ( most likely day ) run query to get aggregated data and put it in another collection , also with indexes , which you are going to query from no on.
After that you'll remove agregated data if you don't need it anymore.

Here is [help page on indexes](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.ensureIndex/) and [faq](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/indexes/)

In you case it is going to be

```
 db.events.ensureIndex({counterId:1,serverId:2, datetime:3 })
```

You may play with sequence of fields in index, as it may lead to different results.

Also if you are going to aggregate once an hour as i said, you'll better put datetime as first indexed field

```
 db.events.ensureIndex({datetime:1, counterId:2,serverId:3 })
```

NOTE: obviously adding indexes will improve speed of reading data from collection, but will slow down writing data to it.

Comment: Cause of I use MongoDb in there  , there is 7 million data for a 1 day and we want to show data of 1 year so we have very huge sized data . For reducing size of data we decided to use mongodb.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by reducing size of data by use of mongodb? Using nosql db doesnt reduce qty of data anyhow. it just offer you different api for read/write data to storage.

Comment: Also, if you are going to store data for a year it surely make sense to pre-aggregate data for all available periods ie create separate collection for years, months, weeks etc.

Comment: MongoDB uses BSON for storing data.And It provides much lightweight data for other database systems. Is it true ?

Comment: Well to be frank that would be last thing I would think about when choosing database engine. I never compared mongo db vs sql db storing same amout of alike data, but given your scale I don't belive difference wouldn't be so drastic